# Text Tabs Grouping

Tags: docusignapi

We have a W9 from the has 5 fields 3 Blocks for the SSN or 2 Blocks for an FEIN.  One of the 2 options is required but I can't figure out how that logic would work. Initially I has thinking of something like a nested tab group but I'm not sure how I would accomplish that, or if I even can. So group 'A' be the 3 SSN fields all required, group 'B' would be FEIN Fields all required and Group 'C' would somehow Check groups 'A' and 'B' and make sure one passes. We also don't know which option the Signer will be filling in.  My other idea is for the CSR to complete that from our side before sending the W9 but that's not the preference.

We are currently using the SDK to send the Documents from a C# application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign doesn't have the capability to handle logical operators in the way that you described above. The instance that you're describing wouldn't really be possible unless you knew which blocks the signer wanted to use. What you could do is setup a radio button with two options, one for SSN and one for FEIN so that the signer has to choose one. Once they've chosen their desired option, the relevant text fields appear by using [conditional logic](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-conditional-fields) so that the signer has to enter either their SSN or FEIN information, depending on their choice.

If you want them to have the option to enter information into both and ensure that at least one is entered, the best approach would probably be to have them enter it prior to accessing the envelope and pass that information into the envelope that you create.